# CmisUnauthorizedException: Unauthorized - error using Apache Chemistry library interfacing to Sharepoint 2013

Tags: java, sharepoint-2013, cmis, apache-chemistry

I'm having concern connecting to Sharepoint 2013 via CMIS using Apache Chemistry library.

I am receiving **Unauthorized error**, but the credentials (U/P) I used are correct.

I used it to login to the Sharepoint Online so it should be working on my code.

Hope someone could help me solving this. Thanks!

See my code below I am using to create a session to Sharepoint:

```
public Session fillParams()    {//define some values for the connection string
    String rest_base = "http://<server>/sites/_api/web/";
    String repository_id = "c013ab76-4821-489f-9a1c-1d43bfce1c32";
    String atompub_url = rest_base + "/" + repository_id + "";
    String username ="notTobeShown";
    String password = "notTobeShown";
    SessionFactory factory = SessionFactoryImpl.newInstance();
    Map<String, String> parameter = new HashMap<String,String>();

    parameter.put(SessionParameter.ATOMPUB_URL, rest_base);
    parameter.put(SessionParameter.BINDING_TYPE, BindingType.ATOMPUB.value());
    parameter.put(SessionParameter.AUTH_HTTP_BASIC, "true");
    parameter.put(SessionParameter.USER, username);
    parameter.put(SessionParameter.PASSWORD, password);
    System.out.println("Pfft");
    List<Repository> repositories = factory.getRepositories(parameter);
    System.out.println("repositories: " + repositories.size());
    return repositories.get(0).createSession();
}
```

For the complete exception stacktrace, please see below:

> Exception in thread "main"
>   **org.apache.chemistry.opencmis.commons.exceptions.CmisUnauthorizedException:
>   Unauthorized**  at
>   org.apache.chemistry.opencmis.client.bindings.spi.atompub.AbstractAtomPubService.convertStatusCode(AbstractAtomPubService.java:466)
>     at
>   org.apache.chemistry.opencmis.client.bindings.spi.atompub.AbstractAtomPubService.read(AbstractAtomPubService.java:619)
>     at
>   org.apache.chemistry.opencmis.client.bindings.spi.atompub.AbstractAtomPubService.getRepositoriesInternal(AbstractAtomPubService.java:782)
>     at
>   org.apache.chemistry.opencmis.client.bindings.spi.atompub.RepositoryServiceImpl.getRepositoryInfos(RepositoryServiceImpl.java:65)
>     at
>   org.apache.chemistry.opencmis.client.bindings.impl.RepositoryServiceImpl.getRepositoryInfos(RepositoryServiceImpl.java:88)
>     at
>   org.apache.chemistry.opencmis.client.runtime.SessionFactoryImpl.getRepositories(SessionFactoryImpl.java:133)
>     at
>   org.apache.chemistry.opencmis.client.runtime.SessionFactoryImpl.getRepositories(SessionFactoryImpl.java:111)
>     at sample.CMISConnect.fillParams(CMISConnect.java:35)   at
>   sample.CMISConnect.main(CMISConnect.java:42)

Comment: Have you tried putting the domain name in front of the user name?

Comment: Hi Florian, I already tried to put domain on the username and still not working. e.g ( String username ="domain/notTobeShown" or  String username ="notTobeShown@something.com";)
fyi that when i try to do Odata in browser, i get Atom response, but in code i couldnt fetch a session.

Comment: I'm thinking if the URL si also correct for accessing the resources?

Comment: Make sure that basic authentication is enabled for the site.

Answer (score 0):

Click on the gear icon on the top right of your site page. Goto Site Settings ->Manage site  features under 'Site Actions' . In this 'CMIS producer' must be active .

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that the 'Cmis Producer" setting is active on SharePoint site. If still the problem persists, you can try NTLM authentication. You can consider the below code :

```
String atompub_url = "http://<your site>/_vti_bin/cmis/rest/<repository id>?getRepositoryInfo";

//put everything into a HashMap
Map<String, String> parameter = new HashMap<String,String>();
parameter.put(SessionParameter.USER,<username>);
parameter.put(SessionParameter.PASSWORD, <password>);
parameter.put(SessionParameter.ATOMPUB_URL, atompub_url);
parameter.put(SessionParameter.BINDING_TYPE,BindingType.ATOMPUB.value());
parameter.put(SessionParameter.AUTHENTICATION_PROVIDER_CLASS, CmisBindingFactory.NTLM_AUTHENTICATION_PROVIDER);
parameter.put(SessionParameter.REPOSITORY_ID, <repository id>);

SessionFactory factory = SessionFactoryImpl.newInstance();
session = factory.createSession(parameter);
```