# org.apache.chemistry.opencmis.commons.exceptions.CmisConnectionException: Unexpected document! Received: Atom Entry

Tags: java, apache-camel, sharepoint-2013, cmis, apache-chemistry

Im trying to create a client application connmecting to Sharepoint 2013.

Im receiving this kind of exception, seems the response cant be parsed by the library i used which is chemistry cmis library.

Below is my code:

```
public Session fillParams() {//define some values for the connection string

    Map<String, String> parameter = new HashMap<String, String>();

    // Set the user credentials
    parameter.put(SessionParameter.USER, "**");
    parameter.put(SessionParameter.PASSWORD, "**");

    // Specify the connection settings
    parameter.put(SessionParameter.ATOMPUB_URL, "http://bbdurl.bbd.cloudappsportal.com/sites/_api/web");
    parameter.put(SessionParameter.BINDING_TYPE, BindingType.ATOMPUB.value());

    // Set the alfresco object factory
    parameter.put(SessionParameter.OBJECT_FACTORY_CLASS, "org.alfresco.cmis.client.impl.AlfrescoObjectFactoryImpl");

    // Create a session
    SessionFactory factory = SessionFactoryImpl.newInstance();
    List<Repository> repositories = new ArrayList<Repository>();
    repositories = factory.getRepositories(parameter);
    Repository repository = repositories.get(0);

    Session session = factory.createSession(parameter);
    return session;
}
```

**Full stack trace:**

```
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.chemistry.opencmis.commons.exceptions.CmisConnectionException: Unexpected document! Received: Atom Entry
    at org.apache.chemistry.opencmis.client.bindings.spi.atompub.AbstractAtomPubService.parse(AbstractAtomPubService.java:602)
    at org.apache.chemistry.opencmis.client.bindings.spi.atompub.AbstractAtomPubService.getRepositoriesInternal(AbstractAtomPubService.java:783)
    at org.apache.chemistry.opencmis.client.bindings.spi.atompub.RepositoryServiceImpl.getRepositoryInfos(RepositoryServiceImpl.java:65)
    at org.apache.chemistry.opencmis.client.bindings.impl.RepositoryServiceImpl.getRepositoryInfos(RepositoryServiceImpl.java:88)
    at org.apache.chemistry.opencmis.client.runtime.SessionFactoryImpl.getRepositories(SessionFactoryImpl.java:133)
    at org.apache.chemistry.opencmis.client.runtime.SessionFactoryImpl.getRepositories(SessionFactoryImpl.java:111)
    at sample.CMISConnect.fillParams(CMISConnect.java:59)
    at sample.CMISConnect.main(CMISConnect.java:70)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not a CMIS URL. Make sure that the CMIS producer is activated on SharePoint 2013 (it's turned off by default) and then try this URL pattern: http:///_vti_bin/cmis/rest?getRepositories

Comment: Hi Florian, I tried to look on to the sharepoint i created using https://cp.cloudappsportal.com, its a site providing free sharepoint 2013 server but unfortunately theres no CMIS producer option to enable on the created sharepoint 2013. theres a link " http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/59189/how-to-activate-and-use-cmis-for-a-sharepoint-2013-server" saying how to activate the CMIS producer but i have an limitation to do so since it is just hosted. do you have any alternative for me to activate the CMIS?

Comment: Hi Florian, I was able to follow the instruction you said regarding activaftion of CMIS producer, and now I am receiving 
CmisUnauthorizedException: Unauthorized exception similar below link.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24954600/cmisunauthorizedexception-unauthorized-error-using-apache-chemistry-library-i

kindly help. :)